# Is infinite union of half open disjoint intervals "with no gaps between intervals "a half open intervals if the union converges?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, infinity

Is infinite union of half open disjoint intervals "with no gaps between intervals" a half open intervals if the union converges?

I think it is true.

Is the proof trivial ?

Comment: Test it. See if you can find a counter-example.

Comment: No. You need to try a few examples to see why.

Comment: Apologies..... I have edited.....

Comment: No, not necessarily. One can consider the following union:

$$\bigcup_{n = 0}^{\infty} (n, n+1] = (0, \infty) $$

Comment: My previous comment applies still.

Comment: Extremely sorry.... Actually I meant, if the union converges....

Comment: You would need to specify what a union "converging" means.

Comment: Isn't there any concept of convergence of union of infinite intervals

Comment: $\bigcup_n (0,1-1/n]=?$